# Is angularJS's $http used in a push or pull manner?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I've never heard this question answered clearly- "Is angularJS's $http a push or pull mechanism?"

Update: Due to the comment I've received, I've modified the question to make it clear that my question is *not about what $http actually does via TCP*. I'm concerned with *the way* in which $http relates to the digest cycle.

Further clarification:

- option #1: $http is used *pull* mechanism manner (like a suspect it is) and it calls the assigned REST API when it is provoked (perhaps on every digest cycle?).
- option #2: $http uses a *push* mechanism, which means that $http has to rely on server APIs that are smart enough to push updates to each and every subscriber. I doubt that this is the case, but I wanted to ask.

P.S. I plan on running some tests to discover this answer myself, but I wanted to get some scholarly thoughts from all you fine people.

Comment: $http is just sends an ajax http req..server cannot push unless it uses webSocket.

Answer (score 1):

`$http` is a service that allows sending AJAX requests *when you call it*. It does not call a REST API at each digest cycle as you claim it does. And it doesn't receive any notification from the server.

You don't need to write any test to discover this. Just read [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: I've updated my question @jb-nizet. You mentioned that $http send the request "when you call it." I'm aware of that. I guess I'm trying to figure out if you can bind the $http call such a way that it has three-way binding (UI <--> client code <--> server) similar to how firebase works.

Comment: I don't have any idea how firebase works, but no. $http is just a higher-level abstraction over XMLHttpRequest. You call it when you want to send a request. Nobody will call it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's never been "answered clearly" because it isn't really ambiguous.

It makes HTTP calls, period. You don't push from the server using a client call.